# Ubuntu Virtualbox in command-line mode

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, resize

I already install ubuntu 14.04 on virtualbox. Everything is OK, but when I change to command-line mode by press `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1`, it resizes the size of window virtual. I cannot change the size as GUI mode. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the keyboard shortcut in `VirtualBox` to switch to TTY is <kbd>"Hostkey"</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>. The default "Hostkey" is <kbd>Right-Control</kbd> for example to connect to TTY1 press: <kbd>Right-Control</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

To change the windows size maybe you need to change resolution of the TTY, use this link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226308/unable-to-change-screen-resolution-of-tty